# Maximum product of lengths involving secant drawn to a parabola.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

A chord is drawn from a point $P(1,t)$ to the parabola $y^2=4x$, which cuts the parabola at $A$ and $B$. If $PA\cdot PB=3|t|$, what is the maximum possible value of $|t|$?

All I can infer is that the point must be outside the parabola, so $t^2-4\gt 0$, and since cases will become mirror images the moment we make $t$ negative, then $t$ must be greater than $2$.

Taking out actual points and solving (by using parametric form) seems lengthy. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: If PA and PB are line segments, what is PA.PB?

Comment: We have taken a point P(1,t), and extended it to make a chord AB on the parabola. PA.PB is the multiplication of PA and PB.

Comment: I suspect the algebra will be rather straightforward if you solve for the slope of a line through $(1,t)$ that gives intersections $A,B$ with the required product of distances $PA\cdot PB$.  There may be points $(1,t)$ that permit two different slopes, one with $A,B$ on the same (upper) half of the parabola and one with $A,B$ on opposing halves.

Comment: I don't think so. Considering the equation as $y=mx+c$, where $c$ is not equal to $\frac{1}{m}$, won't lead us anywhere.

Comment: Consider the equation as $y-t = m(x-1)$ for fixed $t$, and at least discover cases with *two* points of intersection with parabola $y^2 = 4x$.

Comment: I didn't get your point @hardmath. Can you show what you are trying to do via an answer?

Comment: The only thing you may get via what I understand you are trying to say is $t-m$ is not $\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: I completely worked your problem using the approach outlined above.  In hindsight it does work better to use the reciprocal slope, so that lines through $(1,t)$ take the form $m(y-t) = x-1$, but that's the sort of thing you are only likely to discover by working through the algebra.